# Teradata 5.1: Exporting table into csv/txt/xls with code

Tags: sql, export, teradata

Is there any possibility in Teradata to export table into an external file with some lines of code instead of going to `File->Export results` manually?
The idea is to make such export a part of procedure. 
The code might look like this:

```
Proc export;
data = library.table;
path = 'c:\folder\file.csv';
```

Thx

Comment: BTEQ, as listed below, or Teradata Parallel Transport. The latter can manage CSV without jumping through too many hoops and is definitely more suited to large data volumes. BTEQ can handle small to moderate stuff.

Comment: If you don't want to deep dive into the options of TPT, you could use Teradata PT Easy Loader (=TPT command line interface)  https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035-2445%E2%80%90086K/2445ch12.14.2.html#

Answer (score 3):

When you say "part of a procedure", are you saying part of a stored procedure or just a generic function/script?  You can export table/SQL result data using Teradata's BTEQ utility, which can easily be scripted.

**Sample BTEQ script**

```
.logon <TDPID>/<user_name>,<password>

.export indicdata file=outputfile.dat
select * from MyTable;
.export reset;
.quit
```

You can also use Teradata's ARC tool to backup specific tables.

Comment: Implementing export to a file in a stored procedure would be a big task due to the distributed nature of Teradata. The Stored procedure process is running somewhere on one of the multiple nodes. You could create a stored procedure (with some C-code) to create a file on the database node, but not easily on your client machine. Thats what the database clients are for. They talk to the database processes and bring back the result to your machine. A Stored procedure is part of the database processes and thus don't want to interact with your machine directly.